# Reading Dynamic Sets from File using C#

Tags: c#, string, file-io

Here's my file i Want to Use C# code to make a each set that consist of A to E (from the input file)

```
A,1234,58978,...
B,55785,..
C,5788,...
C,446687,..
E,5456,...
E,4578,..
A,47,78,
B,5,..
C,7,..
C,66,..
E,56,..
E,48,
A,87,48,
B,8,..
C,74,..
C,64,..
E,57,..
E,48,
```

To be very Clear,

my first Set will be like,

```
A,1234,58978,...
B,55785,..
C,5788,...
C,446687,..
E,5456,...
E,4578,..
```

my Second Set will be like ,

```
A,47,78,
B,5,..
C,7,..
C,66,..
E,56,..
E,48,
```

my third Set will be like,

```
A,87,48,
B,8,..
C,74,..
C,64,..
E,57,..
E,48,
```

My file consist of n-sets.So a possible way is to to store in an Array[].So that i can also process those multiple sets with in foreach loop.

Yet, i couldn't find a way to calculate and store this dynamic n-sets of Value in C#.

Comment: use [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Fine. What you have tried so far?

Comment: var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1).Take(2).ToArray()


But with in the Skip and Take function the values should not be static one(hard coded).Since my file has n-no of sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results will be in the dictionary `sets` in the below code. Basically it reads each line and compares the first character of the line to the previous line's first character. If bigger, than it will just add to the set. If smaller, it will create a new set and add to that. It will keep doing that till it has done reading the whole file.

I am using the `ReadLines` method so it does not load the whole file into memory but loads them line by line as we request it.

```
string last = "";
var sets = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
File.ReadLines("YourFilePath.txt").Select(x =>
{
    string first = x.Substring(0, 1);
    last = last == "" ? first : last;
    if (first.CompareTo(last) > 0)
    {
        sets[sets.Count-1].Add(x);
    }
    else
    {
        sets.Add(sets.Count, new List<string>());
        sets[sets.Count - 1].Add(x);
    }

    return x;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks,this Solves my Problems.Also,now i can easily Process each Values in the dictionary with the following Code 


 


      foreach (List<string> list in sets.Values)
            {
                foreach(string entry in list)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Entry"+entry);
                }
            }